# Robot Framework resource and library file difference

Tags: robotframework

What is the difference between resource and library file in robot framework?
I searched google but couldn't able to find the answer

Comment: Have you read the user guide? They are both explained in great detail.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [resource file](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#resource-files) content is in the Robot Framework syntax. When it's imported in a suite, you can use all its keywords and variables, defined in the corresponding sections. Also all its imports (other `Resource` and `Library` it defines in the Settings section) are now available for usage.

The [libraries on the other hand](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#extending-robot-framework) are *(usually)* written in the Python language. They can be ones installed through `pip`, or standalone scripts or modules. In the simplest case, all public functions of a module *(more specifically - not-hidden)* are available as keywords to be used in the suite. For more advanced usage (scope, state upkeep), they have to follow specific structure [*(usually accomplished through classes, and using identifiers/decorators expected by RF)*](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-test-library-class-or-module).

There is a third type of import, for which you haven't asked but I'm adding for completeness - the [`Variables` files](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-files). Their format is once again Python code, which makes them quite versatile and powerful compared to vars defined in RF syntax *(you can set the variables' content through complex programming constructs)*.
One caveat to keep in mind with them -  the framework expects **every** attribute of the module to be a variable, and makes it accessible in your suite; this includes even other modules the file imports :). Thus you have to hide them through the `_` name suffix *(or, abuse this side effect for silent imports in some exotic cases :))*.

---

I've included links to the relevant sections of the user guide, for further information.